Trigger que atualiza a quantidade de alterações em determinada coluna
Tenho um código que faz uma simulação de seguro, porém existem vários fatores que podem interferir na geração da cotação, então eu estipulei um limite de 10 tentativas no meu código e quero controlar através do banco, para isso eu tenho duas colunas:
efetivado_cotacao_majorada, que é um bool not null.
quantidade_tentativas_cotacao not null default 0.
No código quando da sucesso na geração de cotação ele seta efetivado_cotacao como True e deverá incrementar a quantidade_tentativas_cotacao_majorada.
Quando for False o código também manda um update de False e esse deve ser o gatilho para a trigger incrementar a coluna quantidade_tentativas_cotacao_majorada.
Meu SQL está assim:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.incrementar_tentativas_cotacao_majorada()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    RAISE NOTICE 'Função incrementar_tentativas_cotacao_majorada foi chamada';
    NEW.quantidade_tentativas_cotacao_majorada := new.quantidade_tentativas_cotacao_majorada + 1;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$;

CREATE TRIGGER atualizar_tentativas_cotacao_majorada
AFTER UPDATE OF efetivado_cotacao_majorada ON public.renovacao_seguros
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.incrementar_tentativas_cotacao_majorada();

Segui o que o Motta comentou, porém a coluna não está sendo incrementada. A função está sendo chamada pois conferi através do RAISE NOTICE.

Veja where event can be one of:
INSERT
UPDATE [ OF column_name [, ... ] ]
DELETE
TRUNCATE ... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html


Nada que eu já não tenha tentado, tentei tudo o que foi possível e não encontrei em lugar nenhum um exemplo parecido com o meu problema, nem ChatGPT e Copilot conseguiram gerar algum exemplo funcional disso. Comecei a pensar que talvez não tenha solução para isso através de trigger e terei que controlar pelo código, o que vai ser bem mais trabalhoso pois terei que mexer em muitos arquivos que agoram precisaram ter essa contagem.

Em Oracle faço no trigger algo como if :old.campox <> :new.campox then ... Talvez não tenha entendido o problema

Mas aí é que ta, não faz diferença se o valor new for igual ou diferente do old, o que importa é a alteração da coluna. Por default, ela é sempre False. Quando o código quebra ele manda um "update seguros set efetivado_cotacao = false where...". Ou seja, o valor old e new são iguais, mas deve-se acionar a trigger, pois preciso contar a quantidade de False's. O problema é que mesmo quando não há alteração na coluna efetivado_cotacao, ele está incrementando a coluna contadora.

O problema seria então : saber que a coluna foi citada no SET do UPDATE não importando se houve ou não mudança do valor ? Se for isto creio que a documentação que passei resolva , não uso postgresql não teria como testar todavia.

Eu testei antes, mas acabei não atualizando aqui, postei meu SQL atualizado conforme a documentação que você mandou e o problema agora é que a coluna não é incrementada em situação nenhuma, embora ele esteja caindo na função, pois verifiquei através do raise notice. Não sei se fiz algo errado no SQL talvez.

No meu trigger sempre coloco "RETURN NULL;"
E na declaração  EXECUTE PROCEDURE

Testei por o return, mas da erro. Pelo que sei no postgres triggers não tem return. No execute, tentei também o execute procedure, aceitou a mudança, mas não tive resultados.

@Rafael, me parece que o problema é porque você usou o AFTER UPDATE, o correto deveria ser BEFORE UPDATE, não?

Sim, isso resolveu, eu estava testando com BEFORE no inicio, mas com tantas tentativas acabei não voltando para BEFORE, postei a solução acima.

A solução foi alterar para BEFORE. Código ajustado:
 -- FUNÇÃO INCREMENTA TENTATIVAS MAJORADA
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.incrementar_tentativas_cotacao_majorada()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.quantidade_tentativas_cotacao_majorada := OLD.quantidade_tentativas_cotacao_majorada+1;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

-- TRIGGER INCREMENTA TENTATIVAS MAJORADA
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER incrementar_tentativas_cotacao_majorada_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE OF efetivado_cotacao_majorada ON public.renovacao_seguros 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.incrementar_tentativas_cotacao_majorada();

´´´

